# Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Has anyone faced below warning in "ng serve"?

> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.js
>   10:24-31 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
>   ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.

Angular versioning:

> Angular CLI: 6.0.8
>   Node: 8.11.3
>   OS: darwin x64
>   Angular: 6.0.9
>   ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
>   ... http, language-service, platform-browser
>   ... platform-browser-dynamic, router, upgrade

I tried updating CLI and Angular but no success. Code inside util.js looks like:

```js
function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define("@angular/compiler/src/util", ["require", "exports"], factory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I got this error and found this:
https://fluin.io/blog/critical-dependency-cannot-be-statically-extracted, where the author shows he was getting the same warning. However, I wasn't using Angular Elements, but I got the idea it might be related to the same problem, so I went ahead and checked whether I was using `@angular/compiler/src/core` in any of my imports.

And I was indeed doing so.
The fix was as simple as removing the import line, which in my case was:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
```

And then the editor autoimported it as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Thank you as well.  It isn't just this Module, check your imports for rogue imports.

Comment: That's it. Solved the Problem in Angular 7. Thanks.

Comment: This helped me to find the source of a similar problem on another file

Comment: you sir... are a legend

Comment: In my case, on Angular 7, Visual Studio Code auto-completed the import ViewEncapsulation from @angular/compiler/src/core, giving this error. This solved it, thank you

Answer (score 24):

I experienced same error, when I've imported by mistake `EventEmitter` from `protractor` instead of `@angular/core`.

Changing `import { EventEmitter } from 'protractor';` to `import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';` fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Search your app for imports.

There is a high chance that you imported something similar to `from '@angular/compiler/foo'` by mistake.

Answer (score 5):

This warning gets thrown if you are importing from src path

Change the components import statement from

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
```

to

```
import {  ViewEncapsulation, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 5):

I found a similar issue:

> ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.js:10:24-31 - Warning:
> Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which
> dependencies cannot be statically extracted

I recalled using **stringify** instead of **JSON.stringify** and this auto imported (using vs code) as:

```
import { stringify } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';
```

I removed this auto import and corrected the code to JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this, very similar but it seems importing some things from Angular does it.  Mine was this:

```
import {error} from '@angular/compiler/src/util';
```

I unintentionally typed `throw error()` instead of `throw Error()` and it imported that and triggered the warning.

Comment: It just worked like a magic! Thanks  a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error (shown in the title) and several others because I tried to implement a 3rd party library.

So in short, if you get these errors try looking at your 3rd party libraries.  In my case it was a barcode scanning library from Scanbot.io.

Comment: Never mind.  I found the real cause.  This following import was in one of my components: `import { Content } from '@angular/compiler/src/render3/r3_ast';` After removing it several errors went away.  This was an dependency that was automatically resolved when importing some boilerplate code to support the Scandit.io SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me from this import:

```
import { Message } from '@angular/compiler/src/i18n/i18n_ast';
```

I have a Message interface but autofill import feature defaulted to the one above.

Comment: do you able to resolve this error? if yes, How?

Comment: Yeah, make sure you don't import frrom there. You should be importing from the root.

Comment: @wcjord Can you please send the code snippet for importing Message in angular 14?

Comment: Sorry @AlokPatel it's been awhile since I touched this code!