# Rollup, Esbuild | "Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, bundler, rollup, esbuild

#### Problem

I'm currently facing an interesting issue
when bundling my npm package (Typescript) for `esm` with the target `ES2015`.
For bundling, I use `rollup` and `esbuild`. [See GitHub; (Line `71-101`)](https://github.com/agile-ts/agile/blob/master/packages/rollup.config.default.js)

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.default.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*" // Only include what is in src (-> dist, tests, .. will be excluded)
  ]
}
```

[See here](https://github.com/agile-ts/agile/blob/master/packages/utils/tsconfig.json)

For whatever reason, almost every bundled `esm` file has a check to see if `require` is `undefined` in the file header (see image), even though `require` isn't used anywhere in the unbundled source code and, in fact, `esm` doesn't work with `require`, right?

```js
// Added require check
typeof require !== "undefined" ? require : (x) => {
  throw new Error('Dynamic require of "' + x + '" is not supported');
};
```

[image]

I wouldn't mind this check if not every React application that imports the `npm package` receives 100 warnings telling them that `require is used incorrectly`. (see image)

[image]

```
// Warning Message
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
```

#### Question

Does anybody know why this described `require` check is added to the file header
and how I can get rid of it.

Note: I've already seen this post, but it's related to Angular, so I don't think it helps me much: [Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51319209/critical-dependency-require-function-is-used-in-a-way-in-which-dependencies-can)